# Is it possible to create a loop in SASS to generate the vendor-prefix for keyframes

Tags: css, sass

Im try to build a loop for create a keyfream prefix like this

```
@mixin animate_caption_keyfream($Sleft, $Eleft){
    @each $vendor in ('@-webkit-', '@-moz-', '@-ms-', '@-o-', '') {
      #{$vendor}keyframes mymove {
          from {left: $Sleft;}
          to {left: $Eleft;}
      }
    }
}
```

And Im call this mixin by

```
@include animate_caption_keyfream("0px","200px");
```

but its give me an error

```
"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after \"\": expected selector, was \"@-webkit-keyfra...\"\
```

if i try to remove a quote for a @-webkit-keyfreams its will give me an error tow..

how I can resolve this error
thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out: https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation, there's already a gem for that.